# How to show a table when the submit button on a form is clicked

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

Im currently working on a project to display a timetable of a teacher when the user enters their facultyid. I want to display the table only after they have clicked submit instead of showing an empty table while asking them for the id.
Here is a part of the code im working on. The table should only be shown after submit button is clicked.Currently the page shows an input text box, a submit button and an empty table which is filled after the submit button is clicked.

```
<body>
<div class="container">
<h1>Faculty Timetable</h1>
<br> 
<form method="POST" action="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]; ?>" >
Enter Faculty Employee ID:<input type="text" name="FacEmployeeId">   
<input type="submit" name="Submit">
<br><br>
<?php
//$facid="";
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]=="POST")
$facid=$_POST['FacEmployeeId'];
if(isset($facid)){
echo "<p align='center'><b>Timetable for Faculty ID ". $facid ."<br></b>               `   `</p>";}
?>
<br><br>
<table id="table_id" class="table table-bordered">
<thead>
<tr>
<th>         </th>
<th>8.00-8.50</th>
<th>9.00-9.50</th>
<th>10.00-10.50</th>
<th>11.00-11.50</th>
<th>11.50-13.00</th>
<th>13.00-13.50</th>
<th>14.00-14.50</th>
<th>14.55-.15.45</th>
<th>15.50-16.40</th>
<th>16.50-17.40</th>
</tr>
</thead>
```

Comment: If you need to hide something, look in a basic CSS tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

You can keep the table's property as display:none on page load, and once the button is clicked make a call to a function which will make the table display:block.

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" onclick="func()">
<table id="tbl" style="display:none">
...
</table>

<script>
function func(){
 document.getElementById('tbl').style.display = 'block';
}
</script>
```

You can also do this using jquery if you want.

Comment: Tried this..the table appears for a second when i click the submit button and then disappears

Answer (score 0):

no javascript or no css is need just check if $_POST is !empty if the post is not empty display the table

```
   <body>
    <div class="container">
    <h1>Faculty Timetable</h1>
    <br> 
    <form method="POST" action="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]; ?>" >
    Enter Faculty Employee ID:<input type="text" name="FacEmployeeId">   
    <input type="submit" name="Submit">
    <br><br>
    <?php
    //$facid="";
if(!empty($_POST)){
    if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]=="POST")
    $facid=$_POST['FacEmployeeId'];
    if(isset($facid)){
    echo "<p align='center'><b>Timetable for Faculty ID ". $facid ."<br></b>               `   `</p>";}
    ?>
    <br><br>
    <table id="table_id" class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>
    <tr>
    <th>         </th>
    <th>8.00-8.50</th>
    <th>9.00-9.50</th>
    <th>10.00-10.50</th>
    <th>11.00-11.50</th>
    <th>11.50-13.00</th>
    <th>13.00-13.50</th>
    <th>14.00-14.50</th>
    <th>14.55-.15.45</th>
    <th>15.50-16.40</th>
    <th>16.50-17.40</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: Nope this doesnt work..the table is getting displayed at all.